# Getting 'invarient' not found error on creating a react native project

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native

I am just getting started on react-native. I tried the things mentioned in the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/getting-started.html#content).

But on running `react-native init AwesomeProject`.

I m getting following error.

```
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'invariant'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aragorn/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:18:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at loader (/Users/aragorn/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/aragorn/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

I am trying this on Mac OSX(Yosemite) with following configuration:-

1. nodejs - v4.3.0
2. npm -  2.14.12
3. react-native-cli-  1.3.0

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by completely uninstalling node. I installed node with the web package on a Mac, so I needed to do it manually:

```
Manual:
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}

Brew:
brew uninstall node
```

Reinstalled with brew:

```
brew install node
```

I received an error when doing this about the links. I tried:

```
brew link node
brew link --overwrite node
```

I got a permission error, most likely due to the above `sudo rm`. I am not sure if this will break anything, but it is the solution I found on other threads.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Then `brew link --overwrite node` worked. After reinstalling react-native `react-native init` was then creating projects.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11327.

I tried to follow the suggestion of rogueSnake:

```
npm i --save-dev invariant
```

and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `npm i -g invariant`

Comment: Could you explain your answer please ?

Comment: I've stuck whith the same problem as Harkirat Salija. After some search I found this answer from ErmannoS: `npm i --save-dev invariant`. But I decided to try install `invariant` globally `npm i -g invariant`. After I did this, my project was succesfully created without any errors.